# LWJGL and Ogg/Mp3

Tags: java, scala, mp3, ogg, lwjgl

I want to ask for resources on how to load ogg/mp3 files and play them using the OpenAL facilities in LWJGL. The problem is

- I want/need a pure java solution
- Would nice if necessary libs are in a maven repo
- Wav would be nice, too

Googling for this lead to three pages of Minecraft error questions. So, can anyone hint me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's JOrbis (http://www.jcraft.com/jorbis/) which is pure Java and used by the jmonkeyengine.org project to handle ogg playback.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [pure java solution to play mp3 files or convert them to wav](http://code.google.com/p/mp3transform/). However it might be [simpler](http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=1280) to [use ogg](http://www.devmaster.net/articles/openal-tutorials/lesson8.php).

Comment: I see the `ogg` support is not pure Java, so that might not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use openal with slick and lwjgl? It provides support for aif mp3 wav ogg. There are tutorials on the lwjgl wiki.